# Minimap config in lua

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin

Sorry if the question looks dumb, is it possible to set the config file of [minimap](https://github.com/wfxr/minimap.vim) in lua ?

I test the following, but the plugin is not found (the package command works wheel eg. `Minimap` or `MinimapClose`).

the error

```
plugin/minimap.lua:4: module 'minimap' not found
```

plugin file

```lua
local status, packer = pcall(require, 'packer')

if (not status) then
  print(' Packer is not installed')
  return
end

vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

packer.startup(
  function(use)
    ... other plugins
    use {'wfxr/minimap.vim', as = 'minimap'}
  end
)
```

and my config file for minimap

```lua
local status, minimap = pcall(require, 'minimap')
if (not status) then return end

minimap.setup({
  config = function ()
    vim.g.minimap_width = 10
    vim.g.minimap_auto_start = 1
    vim.g.minimap_auto_start_win_enter = 1
  end
})
```

Comment: minimap.vim is not a lua module/plugin so you cannot require it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are receiving is caused by you attempting to call the setup function of a Vimscript plugin. Remember that Vimscript plugins do not need a `setup()` function and not all Lua plugins need them either. In your case, you would need to define your global variables before the plugin is loaded:

**run this before Packer loads your plugin**:

```lua
vim.g.minimap_width = 10
vim.g.minimap_auto_start = 1
vim.g.minimap_auto_start_win_enter = 1
```

**Plugin Spec**:

```lua
use {
  'wfxr/minimap.vim',
  as = 'minimap',
}
```

Comment: there is no way to put this configuration in another .lua file?

Comment: It is possible, but the standard for Packer is putting configurations in the config function. It would be more ideal to put very large configurations in a separate file.

Comment: @Hadock looking back at this, I forgot that you need to define globals before the plugin is loaded. I will edit my answer to reflect this. I had not seen your edit to the question.